# If with many condition in Ocaml

Tags: ocaml

I'm a beginner in `oCaml` and I have an error on this following function :

```
let rec determinant n m1 = 
    if n <= 2 then 
        detMat2 m1
    else 
        let mat = Array.make_matrix (n-1) (n-1) 0 in 
            for ligne = 0 to (n-1) do
                for colonne = 0 to (n-1) do
                    for i = 0 to (n-1) do
                        for j = 0 to (n-1) do
                            if i != (n-1) && j != (n-1) then 
                                else if (i != ligne && j != colonne) then
                                    mat.(i).(j) <- m1.(ligne).(colonne)
                                else if i != ligne && j = colonne then 
                                    mat.(i).(j) <- m1.(ligne).(colonne+1)
                                else if i = ligne && j != colonne then
                                    mat.(i).(j) <- m1.(ligne+1).(colonne)
                                else if i = ligne && j = colonne then 
                                    mat.(i).(j) <- m1.(ligne+1).(colonne+1)                     
                        done                
                    done    
                done
            done;
    determinant (n-1) mat;;
```

I get this following error :

```
File "s2.ml", line 65, characters 9-13:
Error: Syntax error
```

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Please edit your post. Your error message doesn't correspond to the actual code we see (there's no line 65) and this is not a minimal example.

Answer (score 4):

As there are much fewer than 65 lines in the code excerpt you show us, the error message is clearly not the one you get from this code alone. Please take the time to create a [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

That said, the `then` branch of the `if` immediately following the innermost `for` loop is empty. You can't do that in OCaml: if there's nothing to do, it should be said explicitly by returning `()` (the only value of the `unit` type), as in

```
if i != (n-1) && j != (n-1) then ()
else (* do the rest *)
```